Are finitely discriminable groups the compact elements of the poset of marked groups?
A finite discriminating family in a  group $G$ is a finite set of non-identity elements such that every non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$ contains one of these elements.
A $k$-marked group is a group together with a $k$-tuple $(s_1,....,s_k)$ of elements that generate it. A morphism of $k$-marked groups $(G,(s_1,...,s_k))\rightarrow(H,(s'_1,...,s'_k))$ is a group morphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ which satisfies $f(s_i)=s'_i$ for all $i$. If such a morphism exists, it is unique.
Marked groups are thus ordered by the morphism relation $\rightarrow$, the set of $k$-marked groups is even a complete lattice. An increasing sequence in this lattice is a sequence $((H_{n},S_{n}))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with  $(H_{n+1},S_{n+1})\rightarrow (H_n,S_n)$ for all $n$.
Suppose that $(G,S)$  has the following property: for every increasing sequence of marked groups  $((H_n,S_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$,  if $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{(H_n,S_n)\}\rightarrow(G,S)$, then there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that already $(H_n,S_n)\rightarrow(G,S)$.
Must $G$ be finitely discriminable?
In terms of order theoretical notions, the question can be phrased as follows: while it is clear that  finitely discriminable groups are compact elements in the lattice of $k$-marked groups, are they the only ones?
Note that, when we reverse the order of the lattice of $k$-marked groups, it is easy to see that the compact elements of this new lattice are exactly the finitely presentable groups.

No, there are counterexamples. I'll look up where I wrote this.

Your condition, for a group $G$, is equivalent to the following "min-n-1": for every chain $(N_x)_{x\in X}$ of nontrivial subgroups, $\bigcap_x N_x$ is nontrivial.
The group $(V\oplus V)\rtimes\Gamma$ in Remark 4.10 of my 2007 J. Algebra paper with Guyot and Pitsch (arXiv) has min-n-1 but is not finitely discriminable.
Here $\Gamma=\mathbf{Z}\wr\mathbf{Z}$ and $V$ is a faithful torsion-free simple $\mathbf{Z}\Gamma$-module (this is an old construction of Ph. Hall).
